# License status check failure on downloadoing android sdk tools from Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, android-sdk-2.3, delphi-10-seattle

I am getting started with **Android** developement on **Delphi 10 seattle**.

By following some tutorials i realized that a quick way to setup the **android sdk** is to create a new multi device app, set **android** as target platform and build.

At this moment the ide asks :

> Android SDK tools are required. Do you want to download and install
> Android SDK tools automatically?

on yes a downlaod process starts, after a license confirmation page i get:
[image: android error]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: or contact support...

Comment: This is an installation related question, and as such you can open a free support ticket at [Embarcadero Support](http://support.embarcadero.com). In my experience, they've been pretty responsive in dealing with those tickets.

Comment: i will try with support, my experience upto now is total frustration with support but may be things are changed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues with software licensing should be addressed with customer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had a isssue on an  Embarcadero server once they solved the problem disappeared.

Comment: Apparently not, because I just now tried it and got the exact same error.

Comment: Nevermind.  When I went into the IDE's License Manager and removed some old licenses that had expired, the SDK download then worked.